# linear function- how to write Ax=b

Tags: matlab

To solve Ax=b I do this:

```
A=[1 1; 2 2; 3 1]

b=[3; 6; 5]

x=A\b
```

this prints out

```
x=[1; 2]
```

but if I have A and x how do I get b?
let's say that:

```
A=[1 1; 2 2; 3 1]

X=[1;2]
```

b= ???

Answer (score 1):

You would simply multiply `A` by `x`: `b = A*x`